# AngularJS service sets object property null?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have 2 controllers and a service (note the code below is just an example). When I am on the first page with the TestController, I fill in some data for the user objects and give the Users object to the service. When I click a button the gototab method is invoked. I set the data and make sure when I get the data from the service it is all good with filled values. Now whenever I get the Users in Test2Controller through the service the firstname is set but the details property is set to null. In my original code I have more controllers which did the same job and passed it to other controllers without problems. I just can't figure out why it works before changing state by getting it through the service, but in the next controller it's missing 'some, not all' values.

```
.controller('TestController', function ($state, $scope, AuthService, UserService) {
  var users = UserService.getUsers();

  for (var key in users) {
    users[key].name = "test";
    users[key].details = someArray;
  }

  $scope.gototab = function () {
    UserService.setUsers(users);
    alert(angular.toJson(UserService.getUsers()));
    $state.go('tab');
  };
})

.controller('Test2Controller', function ($scope, AuthService, UserService) {
  var users = UserService.getUsers();
  alert(angular.toJson(users));
})

.service('UserService', function () {
  var users = [];
  return {
    getUsers: function () {
      return users;
    },
    setUsers: function (value) {
      users = value;
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: if your UserService did asynchrone task you will use `UserService.setUsers(users).then(function(data){ ... alert(angular.toJson(users)) })` syntax instead to do task only when service fonction is finished. If you dont use `then` so you call the service and directly alert data but the services maybe didn't return the update data yet so you alert obsolet data

Comment: I will change  this part `for (var key in users) {
    users[key].name = "test";
    users[key].details = someArray;
  }` to `for (var key in users) {
    users[key] = { };
    users[key].name = "test";
    users[key].details = someArray;
  }`

Comment: I tried it and eventually did not work either. The alert in then will give me all the values and in the next controller 1 value is still lost.

Comment: did you use everywhere the then syntax ?
`UserService.getUsers(users).then(function(data){ $scope.users = data) })
 `. you have to set the variable inside the "then" callback